# How to set browser language as English through selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

I am trying to run my test which is running on VM machine located at France through Azure Devops Pipeline.
Now I have applied all my locator strategy to find elements as per English language because in local browser, the language is English.

I tried couple of options like ```

```
case "Chrome":
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions=new ChromeOptions();
            
            //chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("−−lang=en-US");
```

```
but still this doesn't change the browser language
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("−−lang=en");
```

Based on definition:

> --lang ⊗  The language file that we want to try to open. Of the form language[-country] where language is the 2 letter code from ISO-639.

See https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Thanks pburgr for reply.  I handled it through option available into application itself using selenium.